Unable to connect to the postgres from spire server
I have to set up a spire server with postgres database as backend. I am following this document - https://spiffe.io/docs/latest/try/getting-started-k8s.
After the setup the spire server and the spire agent pods were running. Then I changed the database in the server-configmap.yaml file from sqlite to postgres as below -
plugin_data {
    database_type = "postgres"
    connection_string = "dbname=postgres user=postgres password=Jj8Rt9tbyc host=my-postgresql port=5432"
}

Then I have started a postgres service in the same namespace as the spire server.
$ kubectl get svc my-postgresql -n spire
NAME            TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
my-postgresql   ClusterIP   10.96.127.179   <none>        5432/TCP   4d2h

rsatal@rsatal-ub20:~/rahul$ kubectl get endpoints my-postgresql -n spire
NAME            ENDPOINTS           AGE
my-postgresql   10.244.0.201:5432   4d2h

But on the spire server logs, I am getting this error -
$ k logs spire-server-0 
time="2024-09-13T10:00:42Z" level=warning msg="Current umask 0022 is too permissive; setting umask 0027"
time="2024-09-13T10:00:42Z" level=info msg=Configured admin_ids="[]" data_dir=/run/spire/data
time="2024-09-13T10:00:42Z" level=info msg="Opening SQL database" db_type=postgres subsystem_name=sql
time="2024-09-13T10:00:47Z" level=error msg="Fatal run error" error="datastore-sql: dial tcp: lookup my-postgresql: Try again"
time="2024-09-13T10:00:47Z" level=error msg="Server crashed" error="datastore-sql: dial tcp: lookup my-postgresql: Try again"

I have no idea what's going wrong and why the spire server pod is not able to access the postgres. I am also not able to get inside the spire server  -
 kubectl exec -it spire-server-0 -- nslookup my-postgresql
error: Internal error occurred: error executing command in container: failed to exec in container: failed to start exec "0089c4fa4e670cc624f5e24d00b27b06356f936345f19c70cf2545e1cf18a78d": OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "nslookup": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

But to debug it I have tried creating a debug container and I was able to access the postgres
$ kubectl run -it --rm debug2 --image=busybox --restart=Never -- sh
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ # 
/ # nslookup my-postgresql
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10:53

